# Is there a way to make AsyncTask more portable?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

As it stands, AsyncTask is really cluttering my code. I need to use it for something, and the doInBackground piece is used in different pieces of code. However, the onPostExecute changes.

I don't want to feed everything into one method like:

```
function doThis(String tag) {

    new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Do that thing that needs to be done.
    }

    @Override
    onPostExecute(String message) {

        if (tag.equals("login")) {
          // Do large segment of logging in code.
        } else if (tag.equals("register")) {
          // Do other large segment of registering code
        } ... //and it goes on   
    }
}
```

Is there another way to do this? Or, is there a better way to wait to process things once the work done in the background is finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach: Inheritance.

```
abstract class BaseTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Do that thing that needs to be done.
    }
}
```

...

```
class LoginTask extends BaseTask {
    @Override
    onPostExecute(String message) {
        // just the "login" part here
    }
}
```

Similarly for other task types.

Comment: i see this point...but if you have multiple needs for async task within one activity... ie:  a screen with 10 buttons that all do something different but all require use of asynctask for http requests... you'd be creating 10 different classes...correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate class which extends AsyncTask. Then create an interface which your activity can implement and its method can be called inside onPostExecute. However you need to pass your activity reference to this new class.